# Akka Actor - pipeTo - Is it inadvisable to use values from the received message in the piped reply?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm handling a `Future` in an Actor with the `pipeTo` pattern which seems to be working ok.

In the example I've mocked up below `UserProxyActor` asks `UserActivityActor` with  a `Get(userId)` message.

I want to include the parameters of the Get message in the response so that the receiving actor has everything it needs to process the message. For example, insert the activities into a DB with the related userId.

1. Is the userId available in the `map` call or does it get "closed over"?
2. Is this going to work because the ask pattern will block?
3. Is there some much nicer way to do this that I haven't come across?

```scala
class UserActivityActor(repository: UserActivityRepository) extends Actor {
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import UserActivityActor._
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  def receive = {
    case Get(userId) =>
      // user's historical activities are retrieved
      // via the separate repository
      repository.queryHistoricalActivities(userId)
        .map(a => UserActivityReceived(userId, a))      // wrap the completed future value in a message
        .recover{case ex => RepoFailure(ex.getMessage)} // wrap failure in a local message type
        .pipeTo(sender())


class UserProxyActor(userActivities: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import UserProxyActor._
  import akka.pattern.{ ask, pipe }

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  def receive = {
    case GetUserActivities(user) =>
      (userActivities ? UserActivityActor.Get(user))
        .pipeTo(sender())
  }
}
```

Comment: does ```repository.queryHistoricalActivities(userId)``` return a **Future**?

Comment: yes, it returns a Future `def queryHistoricalActivities(userId: String): Future[List[UserActivity]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the userId available in the map call or does it get "closed over"?

`Get` should be immutable if yes `userId` will be available.

> Is this going to work because the ask pattern will block?

The actor receives a Get message, creates a Future and then process another message. No blocking at all. Ask's Future is not completed until the Future is completed or a timeout occurs.

> Is there some much nicer way to do this that I haven't come across?

Looks nice if `repository.queryHistoricalActivities(userId)` is not blocking call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry if this is a really silly question but does returning a Future ensure it is not a blocking call?

Comment: Reading this makes that seem like a slightly silly question https://blog.colinbreck.com/calling-blocking-code-there-is-no-free-lunch/

Naive approach = return Future, so that some calls are run in parallel but there's some limit unless `blocking` is used and even then there are risks.

Comment: @Rocco > does returning a Future ensure it is not a blocking call? = actually not. It depends on what under the hood of  ```repository.queryHistoricalActivities(userId)``` call. If it uses regular java jdbc driver - that means that it is a blocking call bc it will be waiting until it reads all the bytes from db and your actor wouldn't be able to process new messages and it may exhaust your ```ec``` bc if all threads wait the bytes from db your akka wouldn't be able to process new messages and answers for senders.

Comment: @Rocco for example: 
 
  ```
  def queryHistoricalActivities(userId: String): Future[List[UserActivity]] = {
      Thread.sleep(100500)
      Future.successful(List())
  }
  ```
  
 looks nonblocking outside but it is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with what you did.

The only thing I want to mention is that I personally prefer not to use `ask` when communicating between actors (and keep in mind, this is largely a personal preference), so I'd do something like this:

```
class UserActivityActor(repository: UserActivityRepository) extends Actor {
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import UserActivityActor._
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  def receive = {
    case Get(userId) =>
      // user's historical activities are retrieved
      // via the separate repository
      repository.queryHistoricalActivities(userId)
        .map(a => UserActivityReceived(userId, a))      // wrap the completed future value in a message
        .recover{case ex => RepoFailure(ex.getMessage)} // wrap failure in a local message type
        .pipeTo(sender())


class UserProxyActor(userActivities: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import UserProxyActor._

  def receive = {
    case GetUserActivities(user, sender()) =>
      userActivities.forward(UserActivityActor.Get(user))
  }
}
```

This does remove the time out behavior though (in your original implementation, the requesting actor will wait at most 5 seconds, or receive a failure, in mine, it may wait indefinitely).

Comment: ```.forward(``` forwards the message and passes the original sender actor as the sender. But ```.pipeTo(sender())(self)``` will answer on behalf of current actor. So your code is not equally the same.